# jScrollPane not workng at all

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time (as always) trying to get jScrollPane to work. Reading the doc from the website it seems really easy to get going but...

I know the link to the jsfiddle doesn't have the includes needed but I assume it's something I'm going wrong with the html.

which looks like this.

```
<ul class="grid scroll-pane">   
     ..... .... 
      ........ . 
         </ul>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/85/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  <ul class="grid scroll-pane-before">
```